# Robot Framework: How to access a nested key:value from a json response

Tags: robotframework

i received the following json as response:

```
{'statusCode': 200, 'Status': 'Success', 'GroupId': None, 'ActivityId': '8234560b-05d8-49a3-92c5-0ae6cea3ff80', 'MessageId': '3c326bb3-9798-4310-b95f-30135441090f', 'MessageType': 2, 'Payload': {'Result': {'Vid': {'Data': [{'label': 'lb1', 'Value': 1, 'Timestamp': '2020-09-01T09:31:30Z'}, {'label': 'lb2', 'Value': 2, 'Timestamp': '2020-09-01T09:31:30Z'}]}}}, 'Priority': 1, 'Time': '2020-09-01T09:37:17.8509538+00:00'}
```

i extracted "ActivityId" as follows:

```
${response['ActivityId']}
```

But how can i extract "Value" from "Data" array where "label" is "lb1"? itried this

```
${response['Payload']['Result']['Vid']['Data[?(@']['label=='lb1')]']['Value']}
```

got Syntax Error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter script expression of jsonpath `?()` to loop through the nodes of array on conditional basis.

```
 ${value}=     Get Value From Json     ${json_object}      $.Payload.Result.Vid.Data[?(@.label=='lb1')].Value
 log to console   ${value}
```

Note: Put the string after == in single quotes and do not add the space between jsonpath expression

for more details on json path expression have a look at [JSONLibrary](https://robotframework-thailand.github.io/robotframework-jsonlibrary/JSONLibrary.html)

Output -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am trying to import "JSONLibrary" and i got error: "Importing test library 'JSONLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JSONLibrary'"

Comment: This altogether new question and you should ask in new post. Still you can try doing - following steps  1.open cmd 2. hit the command `pip --version` if you get the version of pip as output of this command then 3. do `pip install robotframework-jsonlibrary` otherwise you have problem with pip installation python installation. Which is again out of scope here.

Comment: @Nagarjuna    May I know which library did you used if `jsonlibrary` is not already installed?